# SPARQL query to retrieve data from OWL file

Tags: sparql, owl

I need some help writing a query.

Data to be retrieved:
All the instances of "Animal" which have its "flys" boolean set as true.

The OWL file (it's a mess):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!DOCTYPE rdf:RDF [
    <!ENTITY owl "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#" >
    <!ENTITY swrl "http://www.w3.org/2003/11/swrl#" >
    <!ENTITY swrlb "http://www.w3.org/2003/11/swrlb#" >
    <!ENTITY xsd "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#" >
    <!ENTITY rdfs "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" >
    <!ENTITY assert "http://www.owl-ontologies.com/assert.owl#" >
    <!ENTITY rdf "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" >
    <!ENTITY protege "http://protege.stanford.edu/plugins/owl/protege#" >
    <!ENTITY xsp "http://www.owl-ontologies.com/2005/08/07/xsp.owl#" >
    <!ENTITY swrla "http://swrl.stanford.edu/ontologies/3.3/swrla.owl#" >
    <!ENTITY sqwrl "http://sqwrl.stanford.edu/ontologies/built-ins/3.4/sqwrl.owl#" >
]>
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/Animals.owl#"
    xmlns:protege="http://protege.stanford.edu/plugins/owl/protege#"
    xmlns:xsp="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/2005/08/07/xsp.owl#"
    xmlns:assert="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/assert.owl#"
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
    xmlns:sqwrl="http://sqwrl.stanford.edu/ontologies/built-ins/3.4/sqwrl.owl#"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
    xmlns:swrl="http://www.w3.org/2003/11/swrl#"
    xmlns:swrlb="http://www.w3.org/2003/11/swrlb#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
    xmlns:swrla="http://swrl.stanford.edu/ontologies/3.3/swrla.owl#"
  xml:base="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/Animals.owl">
  <owl:Ontology rdf:about="">
    <owl:imports rdf:resource="http://sqwrl.stanford.edu/ontologies/built-ins/3.4/sqwrl.owl"/>
    <owl:imports rdf:resource="http://swrl.stanford.edu/ontologies/3.3/swrla.owl"/>
    <owl:imports rdf:resource="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/assert.owl"/>
  </owl:Ontology>

  <owl:Class rdf:ID="Carnivore">
  <rdfs:label xml:lang="gr">Σαρκοφάγο</rdfs:label>
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
      <owl:Class rdf:ID="Living_thing"/>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
  </owl:Class>

    <owl:Class rdf:ID="Plant">
     <owl:complementOf>
                  <owl:Class rdf:about="#Animal"/>
                </owl:complementOf>
    <rdfs:label xml:lang="gr">Φυτό</rdfs:label>
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
      <owl:Class rdf:ID="Living_thing"/>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
  </owl:Class>


  <owl:Class rdf:ID="Perioxi">
  <rdfs:label xml:lang="gr">Περιοχή</rdfs:label>
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
      <owl:Class rdf:ID="Domain_entity"/>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
  </owl:Class>

  <owl:Class rdf:ID="Living_thing">
  <owl:complementOf>
                  <owl:Class rdf:about="#Perioxi"/>
                </owl:complementOf>
  <rdfs:label xml:lang="gr">Οργανισμός</rdfs:label>
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
     <owl:Restriction>
        <owl:allValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"/>
        <owl:onProperty>
          <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:ID="belongs"/>
        </owl:onProperty>
         </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
    <owl:Restriction>
        <owl:allValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"/>
        <owl:onProperty>
          <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:ID="kind"/>
        </owl:onProperty>
         </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
    <owl:Restriction>
        <owl:allValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#boolean"/>
       <owl:onProperty>
      <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:ID="flys"/>
        </owl:onProperty>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
    <owl:Restriction>
        <owl:allValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#int"/>
        <owl:onProperty>
          <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:ID="population"/>
        </owl:onProperty>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#Domain_entity"/>
  </owl:Class>

  <owl:Class>
    <owl:unionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
      <owl:Class rdf:about="#Living_thing"/>
      <owl:Class rdf:about="#Animal"/>
    </owl:unionOf>
  </owl:Class>

  <owl:Class rdf:ID="Carnivore">
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
    <owl:Class>
        <owl:unionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
          <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty>
              <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:ID="kind"/>
            </owl:onProperty>
            <owl:allValuesFrom rdf:resource="#Animal"/>
          </owl:Restriction>
        </owl:unionOf>
      </owl:Class>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
      <owl:Restriction>
        <owl:allValuesFrom>
          <owl:Class>
            <owl:intersectionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
              <owl:Class rdf:about="#Animal"/>
              <owl:Class>
                <owl:complementOf>
                  <owl:Class rdf:about="#Plant"/>
                </owl:complementOf>
              </owl:Class>
            </owl:intersectionOf>
          </owl:Class>
        </owl:allValuesFrom>
        <owl:onProperty>
          <owl:TransitiveProperty rdf:about="#eats"/>
        </owl:onProperty>
      </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
      <owl:Class rdf:about="#Living_thing"/>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
  </owl:Class>


  <owl:Class rdf:ID="Herbivore">
  <rdfs:label xml:lang="gr">Φυτοφάγο</rdfs:label>
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
      <owl:Class rdf:about="#Living_thing"/>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
  </owl:Class>

<owl:Class rdf:about="#Ellinika_zwa">
<rdfs:label xml:lang="gr">Ελληνικά_ζώα</rdfs:label>
<rdfs:subClassOf>
      <owl:Restriction>
        <owl:allValuesFrom rdf:resource="#Animal"/>
        <owl:onProperty>
          <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="#kind"/>
        </owl:onProperty>
      </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
      <owl:Restriction>
        <owl:hasValue rdf:resource="#Greece"/>
        <owl:onProperty>
          <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="#lives-in"/>
        </owl:onProperty>
      </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#Living_thing"/>
  </owl:Class>



  <owl:Class rdf:about="#Animal">
  <owl:complementOf>
                  <owl:Class rdf:about="#Plant"/>
                </owl:complementOf>
  <rdfs:label xml:lang="gr">Ζώο</rdfs:label>
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
      <owl:Restriction>
        <owl:onProperty>
          <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="#lives-in"/>
        </owl:onProperty>
        <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="#Perioxi"/>
      </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#Living_thing"/>
  </owl:Class>

  <owl:Class rdf:ID="Dangerous_Animals_America">
  <rdfs:label xml:lang="gr">Αρπακτικά_Αμερικής</rdfs:label>
  <rdfs:subClassOf>
      <owl:Restriction>
        <owl:allValuesFrom rdf:resource="#Carnivore"/>
        <owl:onProperty>
          <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="#belongs"/>
        </owl:onProperty>
      </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
<rdfs:subClassOf>
      <owl:Restriction>
        <owl:allValuesFrom rdf:resource="#America"/>
        <owl:onProperty>
          <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="#lives-in"/>
        </owl:onProperty>
      </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
  <rdfs:subClassOf>
      <owl:Restriction>
        <owl:hasValue rdf:resource="#True"/>
        <owl:onProperty>
          <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="#flys"/>
        </owl:onProperty>
      </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#Living_thing"/>
</owl:Class>

  <owl:Class rdf:ID="Europe">
   <owl:complementOf>
                  <owl:Class rdf:about="#Asia"/>
                </owl:complementOf>
                 <owl:complementOf>
                  <owl:Class rdf:about="#Africa"/>
                </owl:complementOf>
                 <owl:complementOf>
                  <owl:Class rdf:about="#America"/>
                </owl:complementOf>
  <rdfs:label xml:lang="gr">Ευρώπη</rdfs:label>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#Perioxi"/>
  </owl:Class>

  <owl:Class rdf:ID="Asia">
  <owl:complementOf>
                  <owl:Class rdf:about="#Europe"/>
                </owl:complementOf>
                 <owl:complementOf>
                  <owl:Class rdf:about="#Africa"/>
                </owl:complementOf>
                 <owl:complementOf>
                  <owl:Class rdf:about="#America"/>
                </owl:complementOf>
  <rdfs:label xml:lang="gr">Ασία</rdfs:label>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#Perioxi"/>
  </owl:Class>

    <owl:Class rdf:ID="America">
    <owl:complementOf>
                  <owl:Class rdf:about="#Asia"/>
                </owl:complementOf>
                 <owl:complementOf>
                  <owl:Class rdf:about="#Africa"/>
                </owl:complementOf>
                 <owl:complementOf>
                  <owl:Class rdf:about="#Europe"/>
                </owl:complementOf>
    <rdfs:label xml:lang="gr">Αμερική</rdfs:label>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#Perioxi"/>
  </owl:Class>

    <owl:Class rdf:ID="Africa">
    <owl:complementOf>
                  <owl:Class rdf:about="#Asia"/>
                </owl:complementOf>
                 <owl:complementOf>
                  <owl:Class rdf:about="#Europe"/>
                </owl:complementOf>
                 <owl:complementOf>
                  <owl:Class rdf:about="#America"/>
                </owl:complementOf>
    <rdfs:label xml:lang="gr">Αφρική</rdfs:label>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#Perioxi"/>
  </owl:Class>

<owl:Class rdf:about="#Herbivore">
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
      <owl:Restriction>
        <owl:allValuesFrom rdf:resource="#Plant"/>
        <owl:onProperty>
          <owl:TransitiveProperty rdf:about="#eats"/>
        </owl:onProperty>
      </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
      <owl:Restriction>
        <owl:allValuesFrom rdf:resource="#Animal"/>
        <owl:onProperty>
          <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="#kind"/>
        </owl:onProperty>
      </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#Living_thing"/>
  </owl:Class>




  <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:ID="eatable">
  <rdfs:label xml:lang="gr">τρώγεται</rdfs:label>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#TransitiveProperty"/>
    <owl:inverseOf>
      <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:ID="eats"/>
    </owl:inverseOf>
  </owl:ObjectProperty>

  <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:ID="isancestor">
  <rdfs:label xml:lang="gr">πρόγονος</rdfs:label>
   <rdf:type rdf:resource="&owl;TransitiveProperty"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="#Living_thing"/>
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#Living_thing"/>
  </owl:ObjectProperty>

  <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:ID="lives-in">
  <rdfs:label xml:lang="gr">ζει-σε</rdfs:label>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="#Perioxi"/>
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#Living_thing"/>
  </owl:ObjectProperty>

  <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:ID="competitor">
  <rdfs:label xml:lang="gr">ανταγωνιστής</rdfs:label>
  <rdf:type rdf:resource="&owl;SymmetricProperty"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="#Living_thing"/>
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#Living_thing"/>
  </owl:ObjectProperty >

  <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="#eats">
  <rdfs:label xml:lang="gr">τρώει</rdfs:label>
    <owl:inverseOf rdf:resource="#eatable"/>
    <rdfs:range>
      <owl:Class>
        <owl:unionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
          <owl:Class rdf:about="#Animal"/>
          <owl:Class rdf:about="#Living_thing"/>
          <owl:Class rdf:about="#Herbivore"/>
          <owl:Class rdf:about="#Dangerous_Animals_America"/>
          <owl:Class rdf:about="#Ellinika_zwa"/>
          <owl:Class rdf:about="#Carnivore"/>
          <owl:Class rdf:about="#Plant"/>
        </owl:unionOf>
      </owl:Class>
    </rdfs:range>
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#Living_thing"/>
  </owl:ObjectProperty>

<owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="#kind">
<rdfs:label xml:lang="gr">είδος</rdfs:label>
<rdf:type rdf:resource="&owl;InverseFunctionalProperty"/>
    <rdfs:domain>
      <owl:Class>
        <owl:unionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
          <owl:Class rdf:about="#Herbivore"/>
          <owl:Class rdf:about="#Carnivore"/>
          <owl:Class rdf:about="#Dangerous_Animals_America"/>
          <owl:Class rdf:about="#Ellinika_zwa"/>
        </owl:unionOf>
      </owl:Class>
    </rdfs:domain>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"/>
  </owl:DatatypeProperty>

  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="#belongs">
  <rdfs:label xml:lang="gr">ανήκει-στο-γένος</rdfs:label>
    <rdfs:domain>
      <owl:Class>
        <owl:unionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
          <owl:Class rdf:about="#Animal"/>
          <owl:Class rdf:about="#Plant"/>
        </owl:unionOf>
      </owl:Class>
    </rdfs:domain>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"/>
  </owl:DatatypeProperty>

  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:ID="flys">
  <rdfs:label xml:lang="gr">πετάει</rdfs:label>
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#Animal"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#boolean"/>
  </owl:DatatypeProperty>

   <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:ID="population">
   <rdfs:label xml:lang="gr">πληθυσμός</rdfs:label>
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#Animal"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#int"/>
  </owl:DatatypeProperty>

    <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:ID="name">
    <rdfs:label xml:lang="gr">όνομα</rdfs:label>
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#Perioxi"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"/>
  </owl:DatatypeProperty>





  <Animal rdf:ID="bear">
  <rdfs:type xml:lang="gr">Αρκούδα</rdfs:type>
    <belongs rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
    >Carnivore</belongs>
    <lives-in rdf:resource="Europe"/>
    <eats rdf:resource="Animal"/>
    <flys rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#boolean"
     >false</flys>
  </Animal>

  <Animal rdf:ID="wolf">
  <rdfs:type xml:lang="gr">Λύκος</rdfs:type>
    <belongs rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
    >Carnivore</belongs>
    <lives-in rdf:resource="Europe"/>
    <eats rdf:resource="Animal"/>
    <flys rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#boolean"
     >false</flys>
  </Animal>

  <Plant rdf:ID="lettuce">
   <rdfs:type xml:lang="gr">Μαρούλι</rdfs:type>
    <belongs rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
    >Plant</belongs>
  </Plant>

    <Plant rdf:ID="pefkos">
       <rdfs:type xml:lang="gr">Πεύκο</rdfs:type>
    <belongs rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
    >Plant</belongs>
  </Plant>


    <Herbivore rdf:ID="horse">
       <rdfs:type xml:lang="gr">Άλογο</rdfs:type>
    <belongs rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
    >Herbivore</belongs>
    <lives-in rdf:resource="Europe"/>
    <eats rdf:resource="Plant"/>
    <flys rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#boolean"
     >false</flys>
  </Herbivore>

  <Herbivore rdf:ID="elephant">
     <rdfs:type xml:lang="gr">Ελέφαντας</rdfs:type>
    <belongs rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
    >Herbivore</belongs>
    <lives-in rdf:resource="Europe"/>
    <eats rdf:resource="Plant"/>
    <flys rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#boolean"
     >false</flys>
  </Herbivore>



  <Europe rdf:ID="Italy">
     <rdfs:name xml:lang="gr">Ιταλία</rdfs:name>
   <name rdf:datatype ="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
    >Italy</name>
  </Europe>

   <Europe rdf:ID="Greece">
   <rdfs:name xml:lang="gr">Ελλάδα</rdfs:name>
   <name rdf:datatype ="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
    >Greece</name>
  </Europe>

   <Africa rdf:ID="Nigeria">
   <rdfs:name xml:lang="gr">Νιγηρία</rdfs:name>
   <name rdf:datatype ="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
    >Nigeria</name>
  </Africa>

  <Africa rdf:ID="Senegal">
  <rdfs:name xml:lang="gr">Σενεγάλη</rdfs:name>
   <name rdf:datatype ="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
    >Senegal</name>
  </Africa>

  <Asia rdf:ID="China">
  <rdfs:name xml:lang="gr">Κίνα</rdfs:name>
   <name rdf:datatype ="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
    >China</name>
  </Asia>

    <Asia rdf:ID="Japan">
    <rdfs:name xml:lang="gr">Ιαπωνία</rdfs:name>
   <name rdf:datatype ="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
    >Japan</name>
  </Asia>

    <America rdf:ID="USA">
    <rdfs:name xml:lang="gr">Η.Π.Α</rdfs:name>
   <name rdf:datatype ="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
    >USA</name>
  </America>

   <America rdf:ID="Brasil">
   <rdfs:name xml:lang="gr">Βραζιλία</rdfs:name>
   <name rdf:datatype ="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
    >Brasil</name>
  </America>


</rdf:RDF>
```

The query I wrote (which should not return any results but, still, it's not functional):

```
PREFIX anims:<http://www.owl-ontologies.com/Animal.owl#>
SELECT *
FROM <http://www.owl-ontologies.com/Animal.owl>
WHERE {?A anims:flys true}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Where are you stuck at writing the query? Apparently, it should already work, except for the restriction to 'instances of "Animal"' - is that the issue? What exactly is unclear?

Comment: @o-r-mapper The problem is that even if I make this change in my query "WHERE {?A anims:flys ?Fly}" (which should return everything in my table), I get nothing back. So, yes, im stuck at writing the query but I guess the problem must be hidden in the owl file..

Comment: What happens if you don't put `FROM <http://www.owl-ontologies.com/Animal.owl>` in your query?  Without seeing how you're putting the RDF data into the SPARQL endpoint, I'd guess that you're putting it into the default (nameless) graph, rather than a particular named graph.

Answer (score 0):

By the content of your .owl file (I take the whole file has been printed here) the main reason it is not working is that you are searching in an invalid namespace. There is no prefix defined as `anims` in the file. You can either modify this using Protege or add the following line in the `!DOCTYPE rdf:RDF` block:

`<!ENTITY anims "http://www.owl-ontologies.com/Animal.owl#" >`

That should do the trick ;)